# Multiple Collection Instances for a single view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, models

I'm working on an app, in which there are two panels - left and right panel. The left panel is a list of different items and when any one of it is clicked the right panel displays information about that item.

The right panel has the same view, only the data differs.

How can this be achieved in Backbone. Currently, I'm creating instances of collection for each item and passing it to the view. But all instances are having the same data.

I'm new to Backbone and I've to fix this myself.

Comment: I don't know how advanced into your project you are but you might want to look at http://marionettejs.com/ - it's a backbone framework which abstracts this sort of thing very nicely.
Sounds like the CompositeView is exactly what you're looking for..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do this. There should be 3 Objects, Model,LeftView and RightView. For each of items in left panel, you can instantiate a LeftView and a Model. And once clicked on any of the LeftViews, you can instantiate RightView based on the same model. You can use the same model for RightView as LeftView is also having same data.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, it sounds like you really only want a single collection instance, which will hold the items that you're referring to (model instances in the collection).

There should also be 3 views in this scenario — one for the `List` (the left panel), one for the individual `ListItem`s in that list and one for displaying information about the `Item` itself (the right panel).

### List

The `List` view holds a reference to the collection and appends a `ListItem` view for each item in the collection. You may later want to subscribe to events on the collection to automatically append/remove items from the list when new ones are added/remove from the collection. This is the view where that should be handled.

```
List = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#list',

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this)
    this.collection.each(this.appendItem)
  },

  appendItem: function(item) {
    view = new ListItem({model: item})
    $(this.el).append(view.render().el)
  }
})
```

### ListItem

The `ListItem` view holds a reference to a particular model and renders the list item inside the list for that model. It also handles the click event, which renders the `Item` view for that model.

```
ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  events: {
    "click" : "showInfo"
  },

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this)
  },

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(renderTemplate("listItem", this.model))
    return this
  },

  showInfo: function(){
    view = new Item({model: this.model})
    $('#item').html(view.render().el)
  }
})
```

### Item

The `Item` view also holds reference to a particular model and renders information about that model. This is the right panel that you're referring to.

```
Item = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this)
  },

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(renderTemplate("item", this.model))
    return this
  }
})
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRGFe/) to show things in action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me some idea to proceed. But, the app is a little more complex. The right view is a combination of 3 subviews and one of the sub-views is a newsfeed, which has commenting features. So, how do I manage the Model/Collection of newsfeed with that of the left view? Each leftListItem when clicked should show corresponding newsfeed and 2 other subviews